# How to persist a complex nested object with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, persistence, nested-forms, zend-framework3, saving-data

I'm migrating the DBAL of a Zend Framework 3 application to Doctrine. The data retrieving part is completed and working. Now it's the turn of the data saving.

There is a more or less complicated (about `10` level) dynamic structure of objects/entities. Then there is a structure of `Fieldset`s, that reflects the objects' structure. The hydrating of the `Form`'s data to the nested object/entity is a matter of `Zend\Form`. So I get from the `Form` a complete object ready for saving.

Currently the saving is working as follows:

There is a structure of `Mapper` classes, that reflects the objects'/entities' structure. Means: Every entity has its `Mapper`. Every `Mapper` knows its "sub-`Mappers`". If the entity `FooEntity` processed by a mapper `FooMapper` has a property of type `BarEntity`, the `FooMapper#save(...)` will call the `BarMapper#save(...)` to persist it. Then if the entity `BarEntity` processed by a mapper `BarMapper` has a property of type `BuzEntity[]`, the `BarMapper#save(...)` will call the `BuzMapper#save(...)` in a loop to persist the data. And so forth...

**How to replace all that hardly maintainable stuff by using Doctrine's functionality and handle this cascading saving in a more elegant way?**

<sub>Some saving functionality will be eliminated by using [`cascade={"persist"}`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-wit%5Eh-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations). But my problem is, that for all the remaining parts I have no better ideas than keeping the hierarchical `Mapper`s structure just replacing of the `Zend\Db`'s `insert(...)` and `update(...)` by the Doctrine's `persist(...)`.</sub>

Comment: I've been in same situation and that was my best idea too. Then i completely removed doctrine and wrote all stuff with zend-db. I think i'm realy newbie about doctrine so if you can find a better way please let me know too.

Comment: what exactly isn't working with the `cascade` option? I've personally never had problems with it so I'm kinda curious